# Development architecture for Oracle database

Tags: oracle, architecture, schema, development-environment, oracle11gr2

We have several schemas dedicated to modules (finance, stock, crm etc.) in an Oracle DB 11gR2. We want to establish an architecture for developers such that:

> 1. Developers will not have schema owner users' password.
> 2. Developers will have time-limited access to DB objects, according
>      to their level, in 2 ways:
>   - Top-level senior developers
>       will have unlimited priviliges on a spesific schema when they were
>       authorized for a limited period.
>   - Junior developers will have
>       limited priviliges on a spesific schema when they were authorized for
>       a limited period.

In brief, we want to organize our way of development in Oracle DB. How can we build that structure?
If I am not clear enough, I can give detailed info to your questions.

Thanks,

**Edit:** I have an intuition that the case is not so clear. Let me give a simple scenario:

Assume that I have a schema (user with objects) named 'DUMMY' which has a table named 'DummyTbl' and a function named 'DummyFunc'. Obviously the user 'DUMMY' can manage all of those objects in an unlimited way, since she is the owner. However, I do not want developers to use the generic user 'DUMMY' and I want them to logon the database with their own username.

Because, I cannot differentiate the privilige level of developers when I gave them the user 'DUMMY's password. All of the developers can behave unlimitedly. In contrary, I want the senior developer named 'DummySenior' to be able to create,alter,execute objects and also do CRUD operations on 'DummyTbl'.

But, I want the junior developer named 'DummyJunior' only to reference the objects and not carry out CRUD operations on tables. The most obvious way of achieving this is to accompany roles. However, we have several issues with configuring the required roles (ie. afaik for 'DummySenior' to be able to create a table under 'DUMMY' schema, he must have 'create any table' privilige.

However, when 'DummySenior' has that privilige, he can create table under 'DUMMY2' schema too. That is an obvious security breach.)

Comment: Possibly, this will help: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6010.htm#SQLRF01310

Comment: Are you developing on servers instead of workstations?  Do you use version control?  I'm trying to understand why you wouldn't want to give developers full access to all objects.

Comment: @dmitry That is not what I am looking for. I have added a simple scenario to question.

Comment: @jon-heller The answer is simple: security.

Comment: @dantedeo Security of database objects can be achieved with version control system. It is more useful.

Comment: @dantedeo I'm still not clear on what's going on here.  Are you trying to architect a way for developers to *develop*, or are you trying to architect security restrictions for developers troubleshooting in a production environment?

Comment: @jon-heller In my point of view those are the same, is not it ?

Comment: @Dmitry I cannot correlate the VCS with my reqiurements. Could you pls explain?

Comment: @dantedeo Sorry, maybe I didn't understand your question. Database side of application consists of two parts: user's data and database objects (DDL of tables, procedures, views, triggers, etc.). To protect user's data from damage you need not to allow developers to work with production server. Create developer's instance and fill it with copy of data or generate random. To protect source code of database objects use VCS. Because, for example, if you execute `create or replace procedure` it will hard to restore previous state. VCS will help you to prevent that.

Comment: @Dmitry Yes, you should not understand my question. I totally agree to your setup for a development environment. However, all the scneraio above is on production DB.

Comment: @dantedeo Perhaps what is missing here is the concept of a "deployment engineer", or a DBA who does deployments.  Typically (in my experience) developers work with 100% access to the lower environments, and then package and hand off deployments to people with full access to the higher environments.  This is extra work but it has the "separation of duties" that auditors look for.

Comment: @JonHeller The structure I want to establish is exactly same with a little exception. In my case, the top-level senior developer wears the "deployment engineer" hat with some restirictions described above (ie. he will not have the schema password).

Comment: you should buy 2nd development server. anyway developers might "kill" a production server with a single ad-hoc reporting query.

Answer (score 1):

For the senior developer you can create a definer's rights procedure that simply runs any command passed in.  Assuming that DUMMY has the relevant `CREATE TABLE/VIEW/...` privileges, this effectively gives senior developers all `SELECT ANY` privileges but only for that one schema.

```
create or replace procedure dummy.execute_any(p_code in clob) authid definer is
begin
    execute immediate p_code;
end;
/

--For a procedure this powerful, grant it directly to a user.
--That keeps the privilege "obvious", it won't get buried in layers of roles.
grant execute on dummy to senior_developer;
```

For junior developers, create a role and dynamically grant it the relevant `SELECT` privileges.  You may want to schedule this procedure or run it ad-hoc.

```
--Create and populate role with some lesser object privileges on a schema.
create role junior_developer_role;

begin
    --Repeat this structure for other objects, like sequences.
    for tables in
    (
        select owner, table_name
        from dba_tables
        where owner = 'DUMMY'
    ) loop
        execute immediate 'grant select on '||tables.owner||'.'||tables.table_name||
            ' to junior_developer_role';
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: The idea of creating such a procedure is a smart idea. However, it requires the usage of `dynamic SQL` statements and the management of `dynamic SQL` has significant operational difficulties.

Comment: No, I think you're stuck here due to your odd security policies.  It seems like you've picked a very difficult middle-ground.  Everywhere I've worked, the organization either had less security (granted everyone DBA), or more (granted DBA only to a small number of DBAs and gave developers little or no access to production and other higher environments).  I don't see an easy technical solution to this problem.